# Generating a new file after processing data in Shell script

Tags: awk, grep

The input file which is shown below is generated by performing results of 2 other files
i.e `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} {print $1,$2,$3,$5,($4 in arr)?1:0}' $NGW_REG_RESP_FILE $NGW_REG_REQ_FILE >> $NGW_REG_FILE`

$NGW_REG_FILE file contains below data based on that i have to create a new file

```
2020-12-21,18,1,1,1
2020-12-21,18,1,1,0
2020-12-21,18,1,2,1
2020-12-21,18,1,2,1
2020-12-21,18,2,1,1
2020-12-21,18,2,1,1
2020-12-21,18,2,1,0
2020-12-21,18,3,2,1
2020-12-21,18,3,2,1
2020-12-21,18,4,2,0
2020-12-21,18,4,2,1
2020-12-21,18,3,2,0
```

What this data indicates is:

```
Date,Hour,Quarter,ReqType,Success/failed
Reqtype there were 2 possibilities: 1-> incoming 2-> outgoing
last field: 1->success 0-> failed
Quarter -> 1,2,3,4
```

I want to read this file and generate a new file that contains data like below (MY OUTPUT FILE):

```
2020-12-21,18,1,1,1,1 
2020-12-21,18,1,2,2,0
2020-12-21,18,2,1,2,1
.....

Explanation:
heading: date,hour,quarter,reqType,Success_count,Failure_count  (for reference to understand o/p file)
      Date      H  Q ReqID SuccessCnt Fail Count
     2020-12-21,18,1,1     ,1         ,1  

Explanation: in input file for quarter 1 both reqTypes(1&2) were present
               there will be at max 2 entry in each quarter.

in quarter 1 for reqid 1 there were 2 requests, 1 got success and other got failed
so 1 as success cnt and 1 as failure cnt


    2020-12-21,18,1,2,2,0 
here quarter 1 ,for req ID 2 there were 2 requests both got success so success count be 2 and failure count be 0
```

********UPDATE******
The answer which is given in the comment is worked exactly what I was looking for.
I have some updates in the sample input file, i.e one more columns gets added before the last column i.e the `STATUS CODE` which you can see in the below input i,e 200,400,300

```
2020-12-21,18,1,1,200,1
2020-12-21,18,2,1,400,0
2020-12-21,18,2,1,300,0
```

The existing code gives the below result in the output file:
i.e Total count of success/failed in that quarter. Which is Correct.

What I want to do is add one more column to the output file, next to the total failed count i.e the array holding those status codes.

```
2020-12-21,18,1,1,1,0,[] //empty array in end bcs there is no failed req,1,success req
2020-12-21,18,2,1,0,2,[400,300] // here 2 failed req,0 success request
<DATE>,<HOUR>,<QUARTER>,<REQ_TYPE>,<SUCCESS_COUNT>,<FAIL_CNT>,<ARRAY_HOLDING_STATUSCODE>
```

I have added below changes to the code , Bu not getting how to iterate in side the same for loop

```
`cat $input_file | grep -v Orig | awk -F, '{ 
           if ($NF==1) { 
              map[$1][$2][$3][$4]["success"]++
           }
           else { 
              map[$1][$2][$3][$4]["fail"]++
              harish[$1][$2][$3][$4][$5]++ //ADDED THIS
           } 
          } 
      END { 
            PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";
            for (i in map) { 
             for (j in map[i]) { 
              for (k in map[i][j]) { 
                for (l in map[i][j][k]) { 
                   print i","j","k","l","(map[i][j][k][l]["success"]==""?"0":map[i][j][k][l]["success"])","(map[i][j][k][l]["fail"]==""?"0":map[i][j][k][l]["fail"])
                } 
               } 
              } 
             } 
            }' >> OUTPUT_FILE.txt`
```

Comment: So if quarter is 2 and reqID is 2, then number of requests is 4? is it right? do we multiply these two instances to get number of requests?

Comment: looks like you haven't tried to do much to solve your issue other than outlining the requirements. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk (GNU awk for array sorting):

```
awk -F, '{ if ($NF==1) { map[$1][$2][$3][$4]["success"]++ } else { map[$1][$2][$3][$4]["fail"]++ } } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for (i in map) { for (j in map[i]) { for (k in map[i][j]) { for (l in map[i][j][k]) { print i","j","k","l","(map[i][j][k][l]["success"]==""?"0":map[i][j][k][l]["success"])","(map[i][j][k][l]["fail"]==""?"0":map[i][j][k][l]["fail"]) } } } } }' $NGW_REG_FILE
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F, '{ 
           if ($NF==1) { 
              map[$1][$2][$3][$4]["success"]++ # If last field is 1, increment a success index in array map with other fields as further indexes
           }
           else { 
              map[$1][$2][$3][$4]["fail"]++ # Otherwise increment a fail index
           } 
          } 
      END { 
            PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; # Set the array ordering
            for (i in map) { 
             for (j in map[i]) { 
              for (k in map[i][j]) { 
                for (l in map[i][j][k]) { 
                   print i","j","k","l","(map[i][j][k][l]["success"]==""?"0":map[i][j][k][l]["success"])","(map[i][j][k][l]["fail"]==""?"0":map[i][j][k][l]["fail"]) # Loop through the array and print the data in the format required. If there is no entry in the success or fail index, print 0.
                } 
               } 
              } 
             } 
            }' $NGW_REG_FILE
```

Comment: Hi Sir, the above code did exactly what is expected, thanks a lot for the answer.I  have some questions which I want to ask you regarding the approach for the problem, the code what you shared did the final task to be done. I will share the approach please correct me if there any better way to solve, Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Raman I have updated the question with small change can you please check it and help me on solving it